# Why is doAfterTerminate() missing from Single<> in RxJava 2?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm just learning RxJava 2, and after refactoring code to use `Single` instead of `Observable`, I discovered that `Single` does not implement `doAfterTerminate()`.

This looks to me to be an oversight, since all `Flowable`, `Completable` and `Maybe` types appear to implement `doAfterTerminate()`.

What gives?

Comment: Looks like it was overlooked, PR welcome.

Comment: @HolySamosa, I created a PR for the mentioned functionality (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/5093), so hopefully it'll be available in a next release.

Comment: @Vesko Thanks!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this operator was missing due to lack of demand for it. PR #5093 adds it and will be part of **RxJava 2.0.6** due this Wednesday.

The closest workaround till then is `doFinally`:

```
Single.just(1).doFinally(() -> System.out.println("Done")).subscribe();

Single.error(new IOException()).doFinally(() -> System.out.println("Done")).subscribe();

Single.never().doFinally(() -> System.out.println("Done")).subscribe().dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, because RxJava was already updated, you can update RxJava2 version in your code. In the moment, the last version is 2.1.0, so add this line to your module's `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
```